# Returning inserted record keys into Oracle temp table

Tags: oracle, plsql, temp-tables, insert-into, sql-returning

I have two tables, Parent and Child. Parent has a foreign key from Child.

I am writing a script to insert *n* records into Child, and I need to return the newly generated primary keys from the *n* Child records to a temp table. Additionally, it will need to store Parent.Parent_Key so that I can use it as a lookup for later (which I can obtain in a join to Parent).

I intend to use the temp table for when I insert *m* records into Parent, all in one commit. The temp table will be essentially a lookup table.

To rephrase the problem:
Parent and Child tables are already populated. For simplicity, let's say Parent has primary key Parent.Parent_key and foreign key Child.Child_key. Child has primary key Child_key and Child_name attribute. I am trying to insert duplicate child rows (for a fix), grab those new child_keys, pair them with the parent_key, into the temp table so that I may use it as a lookup.

Here is the insert query for Child that doesn't work because of syntax errors- is this method possible in ORACLE SQL?

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE DUPLICATE_CHILD (
  PARENT_KEY int,
  CHILD_KEY int); 

INSERT INTO CHILD (CHILD_NAME)
SELECT
  c.CHILD_NAME
FROM
  CHILD c
  JOIN PARENT p
    ON p.CHILD_KEY = c.CHILD_KEY
RETURNING p.PARENT_KEY, c.CHILD_KEY BULK COLLECT INTO DUPLICATE_CHILD;
```

Comment: Where are `CHILD_KEY` and `CHILD_NAME` coming from - you seem to be creating duplicate names based on existing records, so do they get new child keys automatically? And doesn't the child table have an FK of the parent's PK, rather than the parent having a reference to it's child(ren)? Maybe if you add DDL and sample data and results it will be clearer.

Comment: `Returning` clause works only in PLSQL and it cannot work if you do an insert using a `Select` statement. If you use insert statement with `values` its should work. Btw what error your get ?

Comment: @AlexPoole Those attributes come from Child table. That is correct, they will be duplicates, so new CHILD_KEY's will be generated presumably. The Parent table holds a key (Child_Key) to the Chlid table.

Comment: @XING That makes sense. I get *Syntax error. Partially recognized rules (railroad diagrams): order_by_clause := ORDER...*

Comment: @operationcwl that's a SQL Developer message (when you hover over the red line); if you run it you'll get "ORA-00933 SQL command not properly ended". I'm still not sure what you're really trying to do...

Comment: @AlexPoole Hmm, maybe I should rephrase. Parent and Child tables are already populated. For simplicity, let's say Parent has primary key Parent.Parent_key and foreign key Child.Child_key. Child has primary key Child_key and Child_name attribute. 

I am trying to insert duplicate child rows (for a fix), grab those new child_keys, pair them with the parent_key, into the temp table so that I may use it as a lookup.

Comment: You should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49154252/edit) to explain that, not try to do it in a comment. Again, sample data would help. It's also important that you're trying to get the *new* child keys; if it worked, your code would get the old ones (`c.CHILD_KEY`, which is the existing record); which you could do with `insert all`, but that doesn't help with the new key values....

Answer (score 1):

Can't you reverse the order of operations?
Add CHILD_NAME to DUPLICATE_CHILD, and then:

insert into `DUPLICATE_CHILD`

```
INSERT INTO DUPLICATE_CHILD (PARENT_KEY, CHILD_KEY, CHILD_NAME) 
SELECT PARENT_KEY, (SELECT NVL(MAX(CHILD_KEY), 0) FROM CHILD) + ROWNUM, C.CHILD_NAME
  FROM
    CHILD C
    JOIN PARENT P
      ON P.CHILD_KEY = C.CHILD_KEY
```

insert into `CHILD`, with the generated key

```
INSERT INTO CHILD (CHILD_KEY, CHILD_NAME)
SELECT CHILD_KEY, CHILD_NAME  FROM DUPLICATE_CHILD;

commit;
```